# PDO_DBLIB Vs. PDO_SQLSRV

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, php-7

What is the best PDO driver to connect SQL server from php. So far I have found found two extension:

1. sybase DBLIB
2. Microsoft official driver for SQL server as specified here [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql). It works in php7. It works on linux. I have installed. It is working

I installed DBLIB at first place. But DBLIB is showing following error very randomly:

SQLSTATE[01002] Adaptive Server connection failed (severity 9)

It is not for config. Reason if I reload the page that error goes off and everything starts perfectly. It happens very randomly and rarely.

Using Microsoft official driver will help me in this case? Can you please suggest me what shall I do? Which will be better driver to connect sql server and also solves that randomly occurring problem?

Answer (score 0):

DBLIB is becoming obsolete. We need to use PDO_SQLSRV in all place